# Merge two array into one with the same key

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I am trying to merge two array with the same key into one.

After i dump these variables

```
var_dump($allArtistsName);
var_dump($allTracksName);
```

I get this output

First array

```
array (size=3749)
  0 => string 'Avicii' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Arctic Monkeys' (length=14)
  2 => string 'DJ Antoine' (length=10)
```

and second array

```
array (size=2135)
  0 => string 'Hey Brother' (length=11)
  1 => string 'Do I Wanna Know?' (length=16)
  2 => string 'House Party - Airplay Edit' (length=26)
```

Basicly key 0 from first array matches with key 0 from second array.

So i am tryin go merge them somehow.

I have tried a`array_merge` and  `array_merge_recursive`
but i does not seem to work.

How i can solve this the best ?

EDIT:

My expected output would be something like

```
[ 
  0 =>  [
       'track' => 'Hey Brother',
       'artists' => Avicii 
  1 =>  [
       'track' => 'x',
       'artists' => y
]
```

Comment: Could you please post the expected outcome too, please?

Comment: Please post the full code needed to reproduce what you tried, the result you got, and the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

```
$a = ['Avicii',  'Arctic Monkeys',  'DJ Antoine'];
$t = ['Hey Brother', 'Do I Wanna Know?', 'House Party - Airplay Edit'];

// option 1 - artist name as key, track as value
print_r(array_combine($a, $t));
// option 2 - artist name  and track as subarray
print_r(array_map(null, $a, $t));
// option 3 - your expected output
$newArray = [];
foreach ($a as $key => $v) {
    $newArray[] = [
        'artist' => $v,
        'track' => $t[$key],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` thingie with a callback:

```php
<?php
$artists = [
    'Avicii',
    'Arctic Monkeys',
    'DJ Antoine',
];

$tracks = [
    'Hey Brother',
    'Do I Wanna Know?',
    'House Party - Airplay Edit',
];

$merged = array_map(
    function ($artist, $track) {
        return ['artist' => $artist, 'track' => $track];
    },
    $artists,
    $tracks
);

print_r($merged);
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [artist] => Avicii
            [track] => Hey Brother
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [artist] => Arctic Monkeys
            [track] => Do I Wanna Know?
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [artist] => DJ Antoine
            [track] => House Party - Airplay Edit
        )

)
```